# Cytoscape set node data in Ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js, cytoscape

I am trying to add a node data to a Cytoscape instance set as a component property. But ember throws an error to use Ember.set. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `Cytoscape` instance in template then you have to use `Ember.set` or `set` method so that this will be updated in template automatically. If you missed, ember will assert you to use `set` methods.

Comment: Is there any way I can access it across the component?

Comment: dont get you exactly. if you got that access to particular instance in one component, then for the other component you can pass it down.

Comment: `data` is a method on the cytoscape instance. It is used to set the graph data. But I can't call this method because of the error

Comment: pls consider posting code that will help me to understand better